# .NET / WPF Alternative

Tags: .net, wpf, programming-languages

I know the .NET framework and WPF pretty well, but I think the whole thing has gotten too blown up, especially for small apps as the whole .NET framework 3.5 weighs 197 MB by now.

I am looking for a language/framework/library that provides functionality similar to that of WPF (animations, gradients, a.s.o.) and the .NET framework (of course not everything, but the basic features) and which is faster and more lightweight than the .NET framework and creates smaller and faster applications than the ones using .NET.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What part of the 197MB is a problem? Are you running out of address space?

Comment: It's not a 197 MB download anyway.  See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SmallestDotNetOnTheSizeOfTheNETFramework.aspx

Comment: Are you kidding me? I may want to create a small helper app for a friend. The exe-file is 50KB, but then he has to download 197/56MB! And maybe he doesn't have a fast internet connection.

Doesn't it feel like bloat to when you carry a framework with your little or medium-sized app that is far bigger than the app itself?

@shf301: I know. But 56MB still are pretty much.

Comment: @eWolf, .NET 3.5 already has a client profile and you can go to www.smallestdotnet.com which will direct you to the smallest version of the runtime.

Comment: @eWolf, If your friend has Windows Vista (4 years old?), he has .NET 3.0, at least. If he has XP, then you should be upgrading him, not writing helper apps. The 197mb doesn't seem like a real issue (aside from the fact that it is not 197mb anyway).

Comment: Also - what is not fast about the .NET apps that you write?

Comment: I don't have the link now - but someone once tried to rewrite the container classes (List, Stack, Queue, ...) and was not able to get a performance as fast as the one from the .NET built-in classes. To me it seems like the regular .NET compiler cannot create code that is fast enough for basic often-used components, so special optimizations were necessary.

Comment: Except that each of those classes were created in C#. In fact .NET and by extension C# are about as fast as you're going to get without switching to C++. But such performance comparisons are not particularly useful in any real world situations. You can write slow C# or fast JavaScript depending on your skill.

Comment: It's been at least five years since I had to download the .NET framework to get a program running on a machine.  And my customers' IT environments may be charitably described as "not exactly cutting-edge."

Comment: I once read that it would not be possible to keep up the current performance of Windows if all apps shipped with it were written for .NET. What do you think about this? 

Back to topic: Can't someone show me something entirely new, not .NET-based? At least for trying it out...

Comment: The question is based on a false premise.  .NET is not fast because someone tried to replicate List and Queue and could not duplicate the performance of the built-in BCL clases?  .NET is not fast because someone once said that if Windows were implemented in it, Windows would not be fast?  This isn't a real question.

Comment: Do you mean to say you think it's wrong what these guys are saying?

Answer (score 4):

How about [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/)?

Comment: I should also mention that .NET 4.0 client applications have a runtime that's about 30 MB and WPF has gotten so whipped into shape that it's probably got better startup time than Windows Forms by now. http://bit.ly/9FeJ6c

Comment: I'm not saying Win Forms was faster than WPF. I'm talking about the whole .NET framework. To the reply: Can't silverlight be used in browsers only?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Aside from getting support for "out of browser" applications in Silverlight 3.0 (they still must be installed from a browser) you can if you want host Silverlight in any application capable of hosting an ActiveX control.

Comment: @eWolf - Silverlight 3 and later apps can be run out of browser as well as in browser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to develop desktop application for windows platform. As everybody points out Silverlight is one option which has great out-of-browser support coming in SL 4.0 and hopefully more support on Mac and Linux later, as well as based on rumors Windows Phone 7 is also going to support Silverlight as its preferred developer platform.

But I dont really see any big issue with WPF/.NET3.5+ platform with client profile support. Specifically considering the large install base of Vista and Win7 your application installer will be fewer MBs with out the client profile. And Clickonce deployment also will take  care of lot of this platform issues for you for free. So the client profile (~25MB) is the extra weight you might need for the customers of some Windows XP users.

All about client profile is here - http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2008/08/20/client-profile-explained.aspx